# How to switch generic routing to source routing?

Tags: networking, routing

I will need to do [source routing](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/) and before going into more complicated setups I want to understand how this works by switching the generic routing (the one created magically by the networking setup) into a source routed one.

The goal is to create a specific routing table and set an `ip rule` to route traffic from my IP through this routing table (which is, as far as I understand, what happens with the `default` table). This is on a Debian 8 with one interface to which is assigned the IP `192.168.1.107`.

The problem is that this cloning does not work.

I first created an new entry in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

```
200 NORMAL
```

I then dumped the current routing table - for a working networking

```
root@debian-testing:~# ip route show table all
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.107
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.107
local 192.168.1.107 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.107
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.107
```

I moved entries related to the real interface (`192.168.1.107`) to table `NORMAL` (what is below is the content of a file `t.txt` which will be parsed in a moment)

```
root@debian-testing:~# cat t.txt
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  src 127.0.0.1
local 192.168.1.107 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.107 table NORMAL
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table NORMAL
```

I then flushed all existing routing entries, loaded the ones above and informed the system that packets from `192.168.1.107` should use the table `NORMAL`

```
root@debian-testing:~# ip route flush table all ; while read name; do echo "adding ${name}";ip route add ${name}; done < t.txt ; ip rule add from 192.168.0.107 table NORMAL
adding local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local src 127.0.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
adding local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  src 127.0.0.1
adding local 192.168.1.107 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
adding 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.107 table NORMAL
adding broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local src 127.0.0.1
adding broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  src 127.0.0.1
adding broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
adding broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  table NORMAL src 192.168.1.107
adding default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table NORMAL
```

Unfortunately now I cannot reach neither le local IP, nor an external host anymore, even though the routing table has been repopulated. The only ping which goes through is to `127.0.0.1`.

```
root@debian-testing:~# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
root@debian-testing:~# ping 192.168.1.107
connect: Network is unreachable
root@debian-testing:~# ip route
root@debian-testing:~# ip route show table all
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  table NORMAL 
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0  table NORMAL  scope link  src 192.168.1.107 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  table NORMAL  scope link  src 192.168.1.107 
local 192.168.1.107 dev eth0  table NORMAL  scope host  src 192.168.1.107 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  table NORMAL  scope link  src 192.168.1.107 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
```

Where should I be looking for to fix this? Is my approach correct at all?

Comment: Does  `ping -c1 8.8.8.8`  receive a reply?

Comment: Sorry - I should have made it clear that this is not only a DNS resolution problem. I will update my question.

Comment: I also updated the question with the fact that a ping lo the local IP fails as well, but that one to `127.0.0.1` goes through.

Answer (score 0):

It all seems correct, except you are not specifying the interface to use for the communication. Try

```
ping -I 192.168.1.107 -c1 8.8.8.8
```

and it should work.

Comment: I tried with `-I eth0` and `-I 192.168.0.107`. In the first case the ping is mute (no replies). I checked with `tcpdump` and no packets are sent. In the second case and with  `traceroute -i 192.168.1.107` I get `bind: cannot assign requested address`.